# Error al instalar Authentication via LDAP en Odoo

Tags: odoo

Al instalar el modulo Authentication via  `LDAP` me sale el siguiente error:

> Imposible instalar el módulo `auth_ldap` porqué hay una dependencia
>   externa no resuelta: No module named ldap

Quiero instalar el modulo para poder agregar **odoo** al `active directory` de mi **Windows Server**.

no encuentro donde esta el problema.

Comment: Sigo sin encontrar el fallo a tal error

Answer (score 0):

Error solucionado, la instalación la estaba haciendo en el servidor principal, pero Odoo lo tengo instalado en un Docker, así que entre dentro de este e instale el modulo Auth-ldap para Odoo.

Ya que si lo hacia desde la interfaz web por defecto intentaba instalarlo en el Servidor principal y no en el docker.